# In the proof of closedness of the space of convergent sequences in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Consider the the space of bounded (complex sequences) $\ell^\infty(\Bbb{Z}^+)$. Let $c$ be the [space of convergent sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c_and_c0). Then $c$ is a subspace of $\ell^\infty(\Bbb{Z}^+)$. Show that $c$ is **closed** in $\ell^\infty(\Bbb{Z}^+)$.

---

This question essentially relates to the following ones:

[How to prove that the space of convergent sequences is complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191110/9464)

[Convergence in the space of convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199361/9464)

and slightly relates to this one:
[Prove that $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/939398/9464)

---

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $c$ such that $f_n\to f$ in norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ for some $f\in\ell^\infty(\Bbb{Z}^+)$. It suffices to show that $f\in c$ (since $\ell^\infty$ is first-countable).  Define
$$
p_n:=\lim_{k\to\infty}f_n(k).\tag{*}
$$
The limit exists since $f_n\in c$. Note that $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{C}$ since
$$
|p_n-p_m|=\lim_k |f_n(k)-f_m(k)|
$$
and $|f_n(k)-f_m(k)|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$. I want to show that 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)=\lim_np_n=:p.
$$
Everything boils down to the estimation of 
$$
|f(k)-p|\leq |f(k)-f_n(k)|+|f_n(k)-p_n|+|p_n-p| \tag{**}
$$

It is easy to estimate $|f(k)−f_n(k)|$  and $|p_n-p|$ uniformly in $k$:

Given $\varepsilon>0$, one has
$$
|f(k)-f_n(k)|\leq \|f_n-f\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon
$$
and 
$$
|p_n-p|\leq\varepsilon
$$
for large enough $n$. On the other hand, (*) implies that for each $n$, there exists $K_n>0$ such that 
$$
|f_n(k)-p_n|\leq\varepsilon
$$ 
for $k\geq K_n$. I don't see how to go on since $K_n$ may not be independent of $n$. I was also trying to show that $\{f(k)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, the same issue arises.

I'm wondering if I am on the right direction. Could anyone help me with (**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n$ doesn't appear on the left side of (**), there's no need to estimate uniformly in $n$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose any $n$ such that $\|f_n - f\| \le \varepsilon$ and $|p_n - p| \le \varepsilon$.  We only need one such $n$, and you showed there always is one (in fact there are a lot)  Then there exists a $K$ (which happens to depend on $n$) such that for $k \ge K$ we have $|f_n(k) - p_n| \le \varepsilon$.

Then we are done: we showed that for any $\varepsilon$ there exists $K$ such that for $k \ge K$ we have $|f(k) - p| \le 3 \varepsilon$.  The way we got from $\varepsilon$ to $K$ happened to go through $n$, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't expect that I was bothered with the quantifiers. Thank you!